# корректно ли поведение signal?

Tags: c, debian, signal

Пытаюсь научиться работать с сигналами. работаю в виртуальной машине, система debian.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

size_t usr1 = 0;
size_t usr2 = 0;

void handler1(int signalno)
{
    usr1++;
//signal(SIGUSR1, handler1);
}

void handler2(int signalno)
{
    usr2++;
//signal(SIGUSR2, handler2);
}

void stop(int signalno)
{
    printf("%zu %zu\n", usr1, usr2);
    _exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler1);
    signal(SIGUSR2, handler2);
    signal(SIGTERM, stop);
    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

данный код считает количество пришедших SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2 и выводит их по сигналу SIGTERM.

Проблемы состоят в следующем. при компиляции с флагом -std=c11, если послать в программу 2 сигнала SIGUSR1 или 2 сигнала SIGUSR2 программа завершается с ошибкой (был принят пользовательский сигнал, если послать только по 1 сигналу и завершить по SIGTERM, то на выводе получаем 1 1). Если компилировать без этого флага тот всё работает нормально в виртуальной машине, но в системе где необходимо сдать задачу - не работает. Если использовать закомменченное назначение сигнала в handler1 и handler2, то программа отрабатывает всё нормально. Как избавиться от такого поведения и назначить обработчик сигналу только 1 раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае `-std=c11` функция `signal()` в Linux ведет себя, как [sysv_signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysv_signal.3.html).

Она сбрасывает обработчик сигнала в состояние по умолчанию после первой реакции на сигнал, поэтому вызов функции обработки надо снова заказывать внутри обработчика сигнала.

Поскольку по умолчанию SIGUSR1 и SIGUSR2 завершают программу, то она перестает работать при отсылке ей второго такого сигнала, если Вы комментируете вызов `signal()` в коде обработчика.

> Как избавиться от такого поведения и назначить обработчик сигналу
>   только 1 раз?

```
#define signal bsd_signal
```

может спасти Вас (если уж поставлены столь жесткие условия).

Но все же лучше использовать [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), которая позволяет гибко управлять обработкой сигналов. Если устраивает ее поведение по умолчанию, т.е. хотите заполнить только поле `sa_handler`, то не забудьте перед этим обнулить всю структуру.

В любом случае при `-std=c11` (для gcc) требуется еще и определить макро `_XOPEN_SOURCE`
(либо напишите `#define  _XOPEN_SOURCE` перед `#include ...`,
либо вызывайте `gcc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -std=c11 ...`)

Comment: "Она сбрасывает обработчик сигнала в состояние по умолчанию после первой реакции на сигнал" - на всякий случай пояснить бы, что реакция на USR* по умолчанию - завершение программы, потому так и происходит с оригинальным кодом :)

Comment: @PinkTux, ОК, добавил такие слова.

Comment: @PinkTux видимо не всегда сбрасывает, точнее зависит от ОС. За разъяснение всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
//#define _XOPEN_SOURCE /* если C11 - это нужно */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

static volatile size_t nusr1 = 0;
static volatile size_t nusr2 = 0;

static void p(const char * prefix) {
    printf("%s: %zu %zu\n", prefix, nusr1, nusr2);
}

static void usr1(int signalno) {
    nusr1++;
    p("USR1");
}

static void usr2(int signalno) {
    nusr2++;
    p("USR2");
}

static void term(int signalno) {
    p("TERM");
    _exit(0);
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction set_term;
    struct sigaction set_usr1;
    struct sigaction set_usr2;

    memset(&set_usr1, 0, sizeof(set_usr1));
    set_usr1.sa_handler = usr1;
    sigfillset(&set_usr1.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &set_usr1, NULL);

    memset(&set_usr2, 0, sizeof(set_usr2));
    set_usr2.sa_handler = usr2;
    sigfillset(&set_usr2.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &set_usr2, NULL);

    memset(&set_term, 0, sizeof(set_term));
    set_term.sa_handler = term;
    sigfillset(&set_term.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &set_term, NULL);

    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

фунций `signal()` устанавливает обработчик в ASCI C.

Лучше воспользоваться POSIX функцией `sigaction()`

```
 struct sigaction act;

 act.sa_handler = handler1;
 sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL);
```

И Вот так желательно не делать

```
while(1){}
```

лучше так

```
for(;;){
   sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Нужно сделать именно  с signal. мне непонятно поведение самой программы. Возможно из-за того что не Posix. Делается всё в учебных целях. Так же делал до этого как вы советовали, но пока сегфолтится на выходе из обработчика сигнала.
добавил еще sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
а функция обработки:
 void signal_handler(int signalno, siginfo_t *si, void *unused)
{
    if (signalno==SIGUSR1) usr1++;
    if (signalno==SIGUSR1) usr2++;
}

Comment: @Bambaleila, поскольку заполняете не все поля `struct sigaction act`, то для корректного дефолтного поведения ее надо сначала обнулить.